# Go to month and year directly on DateTimePicker in C#

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

how can I achieve that if the User types in the day in my `DateTimePicker` it focuses automatically the month part of it, and after typing that one in it goes to the Year part?
Because I don't want him to have to press the right-key to focus it... is there a way to do this programmatically?

It is not possible that the user clicks already on the month or year part, because he does all with the keyboard, and focuses the `DateTimePicker` by pressing TAB.

The Format is short: `DD/MM/YYYY`...

Anybody knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the event valuechanged

try this:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{Right}");
    }
```

basically the focused part changes when you press the right arrow 
that code line simulate a right arrow key press

Comment: i thought of that too but what then?? how can i focus the single parts of the DateTimePicker?